# Why Java's list iterator is not returning the right element when changing direction

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator, listiterator

I have the following piece of code:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");
list.add("6");
ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
String str = iterator.next();
System.out.println(str);
str = iterator.next();
System.out.println(str);
str = iterator.next();
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println("switch direction");
str = iterator.previous();
System.out.println(str);
str = iterator.previous();
System.out.println(str);
```

the output is this:

```
1
2
3
switch direction
3
2
```

I would expect to print **2** on first **iterator.previous()** call, but is not. It gaves me the same element, it is like this function is doing nothing on it's first call.

the same thing happens if I start the iteration from the last to the first and I change direction in the middle back to the last.

Is there a design reason for that or could it be just a bug in Java's list iterator?

I am using:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--)

> (Note that alternating calls to `next` and `previous` will return the same
>   element repeatedly.)

The javadoc also describes

> An iterator for a list of length n has n+1 possible cursor positions,
>   as illustrated by the carets (^) below:

```
                     Element(0)   Element(1)   Element(2)   ... Element(n-1)
cursor positions:  ^            ^            ^            ^                  ^
```

If the cursor is before `Element(0)`, and you do a `next()`, it will consume `Element(0)` and move ahead. When you do a `previous`, it will again consume `Element(0)`, and move behind.

Comment: Also from Javadoc: A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next()

Answer (score 2):

It is by design, according to the [Javadocs for `ListIteator`'s `previous` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--).

> Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list backwards, or intermixed with calls to next() to go back and forth. (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)

You can think of the iterator's current position as immediately before the next item to be returned, and immediately after the previous item to be returned.

The visualization after the last `next`, but before the first `previous`, after `3` is printed for the first time:

```
 [ "1" ] [ "2" ] [ "3" ] [ "4 "]
                        ^
```

The visualization after the first `previous`, when `3` is printed for the second time:

```
 [ "1" ] [ "2" ] [ "3" ] [ "4 "]
                ^
```

(This is how the `ListIterator` javadocs depicts the current position.)